# How to handle JavaScript events attached with `data-*` attributes when the DOM changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to handle links with `data-*` attributes the correct way when some HTML element is dynamically added to the DOM. That is, in my view file I have the following:

```
<div id="css_id">
  <%= link_to("Title 1", link_path, :remote => true, "data-custom-target" => "css_id"}) %>
</div>
```

In my `application.js` file I have:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[data-custom-target]').on('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
    css_selector = $(this).data('custom-target');
    target = $("#" + css_selector);

    target.replaceWith(data);
  });
});
```

When I click on the above link then (on AJAX response success) the container `div` is replaced with the following rendered code:

```
<div id="css_id">
  <%= link_to("Title 2", link_path, :remote => true, "data-custom-target" => "css_id"}) %>
</div>
```

As you can see, the new rendered code contains a similar link element with the `data-custom-target` attribute set. However, if I re-click on the link then the `application.js` seems to *not* have effect as in the first case: it seems do not "bind" the `$('a[data-custom-target]').on('ajax:success', ...)` to the new rendered link.

What is the problem? How can I solve that? What do you advice about?

Comment: Because you're adding elements to the DOM you need to delegate the events. For example `$('body').on('click', 'a[data-custom-target],...` will bubble up to body and be handled there.

Comment: I never delegated a method. How can it be made in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event delegetion` for that, which will help you to bind events to the future elements.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('ajax:success',"a[data-custom-target]", function(xhr, data, status) {
    css_selector = $(this).data('custom-target');
    target = $("#" + css_selector);

    target.replaceWith(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: In the `jquery_ujs.js` Rails' file there are many statements like `$document.delegate(...)`. If I would like to use `$document.delegate(...)` what I have to make?

Comment: You don't have to use `$document.delegate` because what @AnoopJoshi has shown you will take care of it.